# Laravel Model Events don't fire

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model with this code:

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

 class Intervention extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $fillable = array('start_date','stove_id','description','operation_mode','store_id','user_id','intervention_status_id','code');

    public function operations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('InterventionOperation');
    }

    public function store()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Store');
    }

    public function stove()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Stove');
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function statues()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('InterventionStatus');
    }
```

then the boot

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($intervention)
        {
          exit("creating");
        });

        static::created(function($intervention){
          exit("created");
        });

        static::updating(function($intervention)
        {
          exit("updating");
        });
    }
```

the controller:

```
$intervention = new \Intervention(\Input::all());
$status = \Status::find(\Input::get('status')['id']);
$interventionStatus = new \InterventionStatus();
$interventionStatus->change_status_date = new \DateTime();
$interventionStatus->status()->associate($status);
$interventionStatus->description = "";

$user = \Auth::user();
$store = $user->store;
$intervention->store()->associate($store);
$intervention->user()->associate($user);
$intervention->request_date = new \DateTime();

$intervention->save();
...
```

but when save model, creating callback is not call.

I have try put exit("test") after parent::boot(); and exit is triggered.

If I put event's code in app/start/global.php it work.

I have try use the code in another model and work. 
I do not know why it does not work.

**Resolved:**

I recreated the database and now everything works. Probably, in the various attempts to save, some relationship was skipped.
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I copied the code from your question into an existing model with no `boot` method and tested.  I was able to see the event output, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the full model and the code where you save the model?

Comment: Try static::saving instead of static::creating.

Comment: I split the boot function because it was not formatted. thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Brian but it does not work.

Comment: What if you try to register the callback from outside the class (right before you create a new instance): `\Intervention::creating(function(){ ... });`

Comment: I added \Intervention::creating(function(){ ... }); in the controller before create model and it work, but I prefer put the function in model.

Comment: Can you just return false; instead of exit?

Comment: unfortunately it does not work if I return false;

Comment: @RiccardoDegan Okay. So if you use `\Intervention` instead of `static` inside the boot method? Does that work too?

Comment: Intervention::creating instead if static::creating

Comment: if try put inside `public static function boot(){`  `Intervention::creating(function($intervention)` or `\Intervention::creating(function($intervention)`but it does not work

Comment: Yes is very weird, I don't understand how it work in other models.
Thanks for help in any case! For now I'll put this code in global.php

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a typo: `public function statues()` where I think you mean `public function status()`

Comment: Just to be clear the model is being saved? It's just not firing the creating method.

Comment: @Brian yes the model is saved, just not firing the creating method.

Comment: What happens when you use the model’s class name instead of `static`, i.e. `Intervention::saving(function($model) { /* callback */ })`?

Comment: Nothing, the callback is not fired.

Comment: Try renaming your model to something like `Intervention2`

Comment: If I try to rename, fails because not find the correct file.

Comment: You have to rename every usage (and also the filename) and then run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You could check with `Event::hasListeners('eloquent.created: Intervention');` if the thing is registered at all.... Check other variations of 'Intervention' too ;)

Comment: @RobGordijn i had try Event::hasListeners('eloquent.created: Intervention'); it return false.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to with the namespaces and registering the correct class in the event. Let's hack the source code a bit :)

In: `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php`

Add:

```
public function getAllEvents()
{
    return array_keys($this->listeners);
}
```

And call/dump `Event::getAllEvents();`
Try this for both cases (boot in the model and in the global.php) and compare.

Comment: I try, but when boot is in the model getAllEvents not return events registers for this model. In global that work. I had try call model in a controller without namespace but nothing change.